# How to include color palette into visualizations generated by DataExplorer library

Tags: r

I am wondering if someone include colors perhaps Blues palette from ColorBrewer or Viridis palette into an histogram or any other visualization created using the DataExplorer package

```
#install.packages("DataExplorer")
library(DataExplorer)
plot_histogram(iris, nrow = 2L, ncol = 2L)
```

This is the same example using theme_minimal without any modification in colors.

```
plot_histogram(iris, ggtheme = theme_minimal())
```

Nevertheless, in some pages I saw that it is entirely possible, just I don't know how.

Thank you!

Comment: Is this what you want? `plot_histogram(iris, geom_histogram_args = list("fill" = "blue"), nrow = 2L, ncol = 2L)`

Comment: @Boxuan I was thinking in something like this [link] (http://www.thinkingondata.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Icon3-1.png) I am using the viridis palette and theme_minimal.

Comment: I don't think you can/should apply different fill colors to univariate histograms, or univariate charts in general. It only makes sense when you want to add a 2nd dimension, for example: `ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, fill = Species)) + geom_histogram()`.

Comment: Good point! Thank you for answer me and teach me too.